# detect the vuetify slide appearance

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify slide group and I need to identify the slides which are displayed fully & partially using programmatically.

[image]

So according to above image, slide 0 and slide 1 are fully displayed and slide 2 is partially displayed. My initial code is as below.

```
<v-slide-group>
  <v-slide-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i">
    <v-card width="500" height="200" color="yellow">
        slide {{i}}
    </v-card>
  </v-slide-item>
</v-slide-group>

 data() {
   return {
     slides: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   };
 },
```

My final purpose is to apply a class for partially displayed slides(slide 2) and apply another class to fully displayed slides(slide 0 and slide1). Here main troublesome is to identify partially displayed slides and fully displayed slides. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I had your problem in several projects but I couldn't solve it and finally decided to use [vue-awesome-swiper](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper) which is a ready swiper component for vuejs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [vuetify's intersect directive](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/) which works based on the [intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

use `v-intersect` on the element which you want to detect its intersection with the view port. then pass an object to this directive which has a `handler` key that holds a function that you want to be called each time intersection detects the element visibility.

you should have a `threshold: 1.0` which indicates that the threshold isn't considered passed until every pixel is visible. this way you can distinguish between fully visible cards and partially visible cards.

in the handler function you have access to `entries` which holds different information about the intersected element in `entries[0]` like the `target` element that is detected and a `isIntersecting` boolean that is true when the element passes the requirement you set like threshold and etc, otherwise it is false.

below code demonstrates this approach. in the `onIntersect` method it is adding or removing some css classes to the element based on `isIntersecting` value and this is the obtained result:

[image]

if you run the demo below click on the `Full Page` button to see the effect in full page, for some weird reason it doesn't show the effect in the small demo area. above image is a screen shot of this demo code in `Full Page` mode.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    slides: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  },
  methods: {
    onIntersect(entries) {
      const src = entries[0];
      const target = src.target;
      const isIntersecting = src.isIntersecting;
      if (isIntersecting) {
        target.classList.remove('bg--yellow');
        target.classList.add('bg--blue');
      } else {
        target.classList.remove('bg--blue');
        target.classList.add('bg--yellow');
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.bg--blue {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

.bg--yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-slide-group show-arrows>
          <v-slide-item v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :key="i">
            <v-card width="300" height="200" v-intersect="{
              handler: onIntersect,
              options: {
                threshold: 1.0
              }
            }">
              slide {{i}}
            </v-card>
          </v-slide-item>
        </v-slide-group>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```